# Run Switchery, Select2 and wpColorPicker jQuery plugins in dynamically new elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, wordpress

I'm working on a tiny wordpress plugin has a repeater which has some jQuery controls like [Switchery](http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/), [Select2](https://select2.github.io/), uploadMedia and wpColorPicker.

Is there a way to run event handlers for each control once in js file like Upload Media, it was very easy to bind it once for all new controls with this line

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.btn_media_upload', function (e) { });
```

All jQuery controls need an inline script for each once and i think it's not good, I test DOMNodeInserted but it didn't work and i read it's [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events), Then i try to use the new way [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) but unfortunately i failed to use it :)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best Solution with [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library BUT still need help for [Switchery plugin](http://abpetkov.github.io/switchery/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver || window.MozMutationObserver;

var observerjQueryPlugins = function (repeaterWrapper) {

    _.each(repeaterWrapper, function (repeaterItem, index) {

        var jq_nodes = $(repeaterItem.addedNodes);

        jq_nodes.each(function () {

            // Color Picker
            $(this).find('.element-wrapper.element-wpcolor .color-picker').wpColorPicker();

            // Date Picker
            datePickerControl = $(this).find('.element-wrapper.element-datepicker .datepicker');
            datePickerDateFormat = datePickerControl.data('date-format'); // 'mm dd, yy'

            datePickerControl.datepicker({
                dateFormat: datePickerDateFormat,
                showAnim: "slideDown",
                changeMonth: true,
                numberOfMonths: 1
            });

            // Select 2
            $(this).find('.xx-select2').select2({
                theme: "classic"
            });

        });
    });

}

new MutationObserver(observerjQueryPlugins).observe(document.body, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true,
    attributes: false,
    characterData: false
});

});
```